# CodenameOne - ObjectiveC Bridge - how to read an NSString from a native SDK

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to use the ObjectiveC Bridge library from within CodenameOne as it sounds like a very useful tool. The native iOS SDK is am trying to use is the Honeywell Captuvo SDK. However when I try to call the getCaptuvoName function which is supposed to return the name of the device as an NSString all I get is "Not available"? The code I am using:

```
    if (Objc.isSupported())
    {
        Pointer captuvoShared =eval("Captuvo.sharedCaptuvoDevice",0).asPointer();
        if (captuvoShared!=null)
        {
            Dialog.show("ObjC", "Captuvo not null", "OK", null);
            String name=Objc.getProperty(captuvoShared,"getCaptuvoName").asString();
            Dialog.show("ObjC", name, "OK", null);
        }
        else
            Dialog.show("ObjC", "Captuvo NULL!", "OK", null);
    }
    else
        Dialog.show("ObjC", "Objective-C not supported on this platform", "OK", null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Objc.getProperty()` takes the property name, which is slightly different than the message name.  E.g. If you have messages `getName` and `setName`, then the property name would be "name".  E.g. The following would be equivalent:

`Objc.eval(myObj, "getName")` and `Objc.getProperty(myObj, "name")`

In your case, you are trying to call the `getCaptuvoName` message.  So you could do either `Objc.eval(instance, "getCaptuvoName")` or `Objc.getProperty(instance, "captuvoName")` but not `Objc.getProperty(instance, "getCaptuvoName")`.

One other observation on your code.

`Pointer captuvoShared =eval("Captuvo.sharedCaptuvoDevice",0).asPointer();`

The `sharedCaptuvoDevice` message takes no parameters, so you shouldn't pass the "0" parameter.  It should be:

`Pointer captuvoShared =eval("Captuvo.sharedCaptuvoDevice").asPointer();`

A rule of thumb:  The number of parameters you supply to a message should be the same as the number of colons in the message name.

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert on this so I may be wrong...

As reference for people reading it this is the API you are using: https://github.com/DataSplice/HoneywellScanner/blob/master/src/ios/Honeywell/Captuvo.h

```
-(NSString*)getCaptuvoName;
```

So `getCaptuvoName` is a "message" that returns a `NSString`. So the first thing you need to do is invoke the message:

```
Pointer p = Objc.eval(instance, "getCaptuvoName").asPointer();
```

Now you need to convert the pointer to a Java String:

```
String name = p.asString();
```

Notice you will need the `instance` of the `CaptuvoEventsProtocol` to perform the `eval`.

Comment: Actually, the bridge automatically marshals between NSString and java.lang.String, so it is correct to do `Objc.eval(instance, "getCaptuvoName").asString()`.